# stackoverflow in android TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

When i use this code inside TextWatcher I get `stackoverflow` error:

```
 txt.setText(s.toString().substring(0, s.length()-1) + "a");
```

Why does this happen and how I can prevent it?
i use it on `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged` and both of them generate stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is broken.  In pseudocode, it reads

```
//whenever the text changes, replace the last letter with an 'a'
```

Setting the text is a text change, even if the new text matches the old text, so each time that 'a' is replaced with another 'a' you recurse until the stack is full.

If there were a terminal case, such as

```
if (!txt.endsWith("a"))
```

Then this would not overflow.

Answer (score 4):

A solution I have used is to temporarily disable the listener that causes the recursion.

Note: RichEditText is a subclass of EditText.
eg.

```
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
  {
    ...
    RichEditText.this.removeTextChangedListener(this); //disable listener

    //Change s here. Changes made to s will not cause recursion since the listener is disabled


    RichEditText.this.addTextChangedListener(this);  //reenable listener


   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you get a StackOverFlow error. Every time something changes the callback `onTextChanged` is called. Then, inside it you change again the text.

the doc says:

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text
>   has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from
>   this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite
>   loop

you need a condition to avoid the infinte loop. For instance:

```
if(s.charAt(s.length()-1)!='a')
  s = s.append("a");
```

Comment: +1.  I typed my answer before you edited your to mention a terminal case